# Draw a Ray with 2 CGPoint Using UIBezierPath (IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, raytracing

```
UIBezierPath *myPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[myPath moveToPoint: firstPoint];
[myPath addLineToPoint: secondPoint];
myPath.lineWidth = 10;
[[UIColor yellowColor]setStroke];
[myPath stroke];
```

When I run this code, it will naturally draw a segment (From 1 point to another). I am trying to find a way to draw a ray. By this I mean draw from "firstPoint" through "secondPoint till the end of the screen. I don't mind if the ray point goes on forever (I guess).

Here what it would look like.

[image]

Thank you.

(if you need it, screen size 736x414 pixel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the slope of the line using the two points using the formula 
m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1). Then calculate the third point by setting x and calculating y based on the slope. Make sure that you check for divide by 0.

y3 = m (x3-x2) + y2

Put x3 as the screen width which is 414 in your case. y1 is firstPoint.y and x2 is secondPoint.x and so on.

Sample code

```
CGPoint firstPoint = CGPointMake(50, 150);
CGPoint secondPoint = CGPointMake(100, 250);
CGPoint screenMax = CGPointMake(414,736);
CGPoint lastPoint = CGPointZero;
CGFloat slope = 1.0;
if (secondPoint.x != firstPoint.x) {
    slope = (secondPoint.y - firstPoint.y) / (secondPoint.x - firstPoint.x);
    lastPoint = CGPointMake(screenMax.x, slope * (screenMax.x-secondPoint.x)+secondPoint.y);
} else {
    slope = 0;
    lastPoint.x = secondPoint.x;
    lastPoint.y = screenMax.y;
}
UIBezierPath *myPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[myPath moveToPoint: firstPoint];
[myPath addLineToPoint: secondPoint];
myPath.lineWidth = 10;
[[UIColor yellowColor]setStroke];
[myPath stroke];

//this is the extension from the second point to the end of the screen
[myPath addLineToPoint: lastPoint];
[myPath stroke];
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtract the first point from the second point to get a direction vector of the ray:

```
CGPoint direction = CGPointMake(secondPoint.x - firstPoint.x, secondPoint.y - firstPoint.y);
```

Compute the magnitude of the direction vector:

```
CGFloat magnitude = hypot(direction.x, direction.y);
```

Use the magnitude to scale the direction vector to be a large-enough length; let's say 4000 points:

```
if (magnitude == 0) {
    magnitude = 1;
}
CGFloat factor = 4000 / magnitude;
direction.x *= factor;
direction.y *= factor;
```

Add the scaled direction vector to the first point to get a far-away point along the ray:

```
CGPoint farPoint = CGPointMake(firstPoint.x + direction.x, firstPoint.y + direction.y);
```

Use the first point and the far point to draw the ray:

```
UIBezierPath *myPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[myPath moveToPoint:firstPoint];
[myPath addLineToPoint:farPoint];
myPath.lineWidth = 10;
[[UIColor yellowColor] setStroke];
[myPath stroke];
```